# Tuning parameters for multiple regression models

Tags: regression, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameter, tuning

I am trying to compare multiple regression algorithms to estimate biomass (dependant variable) : KNeighborsRegressor, GaussianProcessRegressor, LinearRegression, BayesianRidge, Ridge, SGDRegressor, PassiveAggressiveRegressor, DecisionTreeRegressor, SVR, AdaBoostRegressor, BaggingRegressor, ExtraTreesRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, MLPRegressor, Lasso, CatBoostRegressor, XGBRegressor, OrthogonalMatchingPursuit, HuberRegressor, Lars, LassoLars, ElasticNet. If I want to be rigorous, I am gonna have to tune every parameter of every regression model using gridsearchcv. Since I am new to machine learning, I want to know if there is a code out there that can help me facilitate the procedure by : automating the hyperparameter tuning procedure across all the regression models, creating the dictionaries for the parameters for each regression model instead of manually creating them...?

Comment: Have you heard of linear regression? ... the point is that there are many, many regression algorithms that don't require massive parameter tuning that you seem to be ignoring.  Maybe explaining more of what you are actually doing would help.

Comment: I second what @jbowman wrote. // What regression models are you using that require tons of hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: Here is the list of algorithms that i am importing :                             
KNeighborsRegressor, GaussianProcessRegressor, LinearRegression, BayesianRidge, Ridge, SGDRegressor, PassiveAggressiveRegressor, DecisionTreeRegressor, SVR, AdaBoostRegressor, BaggingRegressor, ExtraTreesRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, MLPRegressor, Lasso, CatBoostRegressor, XGBRegressor, OrthogonalMatchingPursuit, HuberRegressor, Lars, LassoLars, ElasticNet. I want to compare all of these not just use the linear regressor. I want to see what is the best model for my data.

Comment: A list of your imports helps. It also will help if you write, in English (not just Python), what algorithms you’re importing.

Comment: My objective is to get the best model, with the best parameters as well.